# How can I assign socket ID and do not share environment variables in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, chat

I am writing multi-clients chat program of C++, I have a few problems that I can't solve. 
1.　When a user comes in, the server will `Accept()` the client, then assign a socket id to the client. When the client disconnect, another client comes in, after the server `Accept()` it, the client will get another socket ID. I want to reuse the socket id, but the  `Accept()` will give a larger socket id than previous socket id of previous client. So, How can I assign the socket id to each client?

2.　I use `select(fdmax + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL)` and `for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++)` to scan each every exist connection, and client can use tenlet connect to my server. In addition to chatting, client can run commands(like `ls`, `cat`) on my server, my server will use `fork()` and `dup()` send the result to the client. Here is a problem, if the user assigns a new `PATH` of environment variable, the `PATH` of other clients will be changed too. How can I avoid this, every clients should have their own default `PATH` value?

Comment: The "socket id" as returned by `accept` (which is _not_ an id but the actual socket handle) is nothing you can change. If you want that you have to invent your own scheme, maybe using `std::unordered_map` as a translation table.

Comment: As for the second question, you should be **very** careful when allowing unknown clients to run commands on your system! Think about what will happen if the command happens to be `rm`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg When the client connects on my server, system will change its `PATH` to another directory, but the client also can change the `PATH` as well. My server will filter the `/` character to prevent the security issue. I will very careful to handle it, Thank you very much to notice me!

Comment: Even if you filer the leading `/`, think about relative paths. And you can't know which argument is a filesystem path for all commands. You can solve problems by having a chroot jail (search e.g. Google for this) but then your program must be running as root. You can also solve this by having your own commands, like FTP.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks, I will try to solve these security issues by having own commands and consider using `std::unordered_map` as a translation table to maintain the return value of `accept` and the identifier of socket of my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem: you're probably not closing (`close(2)`) the socket (even if the client disconnects). Although I can't find it in the POSIX spec, typically `accept(2)` (and pretty much anything creating file descriptors) will return the smallest possible descriptor.

That being said, there's likely **no reason** to tie your application to this. Your application should treat `accept` as if it could return anything.

For the second problem, you should change the `PATH` **after you fork**, right before you `exec`.

---

All this aside, I notice you're tagging your question C++: you should take a look at the mighty [asio](http://think-async.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I will check my code and correct it, and try to use `setenv()` after `fork` before `exec` to solve my problem.